# How can I Delete a Todo Task while Making a Todo app using filter method in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am currently studying React.js and I am not familiar with React.js. I am making a simple todo app just to study **'CRUD'** operation and I tried hard to make a task delete when a button is clicked. I heard that it is done by filter method. As I said, I am not familiar with React.js, So I can't Delete the task using filter method.

**Here Is My Code**

**JSX**

```
import "./style.css";
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [toDos, setToDos] = useState([]);
  const [toDo, setToDo] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="mainHeading">
        <h1>ToDo List</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="subHeading">
        <br />
        <h2>Whoop, it's Wednesday  ☕ </h2>
      </div>
      <div className="input">
        <input
          value={toDo}
          onChange={(e) => setToDo(e.target.value)}
          type="text"
          placeholder="️ Add item..."
        />
        <i
          onClick={() =>
            setToDos([...toDos, { id: Date.now(), text: toDo, status: false }])
          }
          className="fas fa-plus"
        ></i>
      </div>
      <div className="todos">
        {toDos.map((obj) => {
          return (
            <div className="todo">
              <div className="left">
                <input
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    console.log(e.target.checked);
                    console.log(obj);
                    setToDos(
                      toDos.filter((obj2) => {
                        if (obj2.id === obj.id) {
                          obj2.status = e.target.checked;
                        }
                        return obj2;
                      })
                    );
                  }}
                  value={obj.status}
                  type="checkbox"
                  name=""
                  id=""
                />
                <p>{obj.text}</p>
              </div>
              <div className="right">
                <i onClick={this.props.deleteTodo} className="fas fa-trash"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}

        {toDos.map((obj) => {
          if (obj.status) {
            return <h1 className="finished">{obj.text}</h1>;
          }
          return null;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Please Tell Me A Solution For This

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your onClick handler you can pass the current todo Objects id which you want to delete

```
onClick ={() => deleteTodo(obj.id)}
```

Now in your deleteTodo function you can do

```
const deleteTodo = idToDelete => setTodos(currentTodos => currentTodos.filter(todo => todo.id !== idToDelete))
```

Note i have removed `this.props` from the deleteTodo . You are using a functional component. So you should not be using `this` to access the props .

So your code has to be like this

```
function App() {
  const [toDos,setToDos] = useState([])
  const [toDo,setToDo] = useState('')
  
  const deleteTodo = idToDelete => setTodos(currentTodos => currentTodos.filter(todo => todo.id !== idToDelete))

  return (
         ....
              <div className="right">
                <i onClick ={() => deleteTodo(obj.id)} className="fas fa-trash"></i>
              </div>
            </div>)
         ...
  );
}
```